# Best way to port an iOS game to WP7

Tags: ios, windows-phone-7, cocos2d-iphone, xna

Does exist any tool or procedure to easily port a iOS game (made with cocos2d for example) to Windows Phone 7 (XNA)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Cocos2D-XNA which is a good port of the cocos2d-x project to XNA and C#. You can find the source for Cocos2D-XNA at https://github.com/Cocos2DXNA/cocos2d-xna

Answer (score 0):

Not any I know, but if you know C++ it is easy to learn C#.
I found this link; http://i2w.codeplex.com/

I dont know if it is any help at all but still.